# Unable to create a topic in Kafka ( Windows 10 & Docker)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

https://docs.confluent.io/4.0.0/installation/docker/docs/quickstart.html

I followed the steps given in this document and tried to create a topic, but getting an exception as shown below.

[image]

I already checked whether both kafka and zookeeper are up and they are.

[image]

I also tried following:

docker-compose exec kafka kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181

I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now by using the correct zookeeper in the command to list the kafka-topics.

**docker-compose exec kafka kafka-topics --list --zookeeper zookeeper:2181**

I got the zookeeper connect information from the docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: You can use bootstrap servers with the latest version of Kafka